# libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

Tags: mysql, linux

У меня не работает сервер только это в лог пишет и вырубается не успевая заработать

```
----------
Loaded log file: "server_log.txt".
----------

SA-MP Dedicated Server
----------------------
v0.3.7-R2, (C)2005-2015 SA-MP Team

[11:10:09] weburl = "www.sa-mp.com"  (string)
[11:10:09] 
[11:10:09] Server Plugins
[11:10:09] --------------
[11:10:09]  Loading plugin: mysql.so
[11:10:09]   Failed (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by plugins/mysql.so))
[11:10:09]  Loading plugin: sscanf.so
[11:10:09] 

[11:10:09]  ===============================

[11:10:09]       sscanf plugin loaded.     

[11:10:09]          Version:  2.8.1        

[11:10:09]    (c) 2012 Alex "Y_Less" Cole  

[11:10:09]  ===============================

[11:10:09]   Loaded.
[11:10:09]  Loading plugin: dc_cmd.so
[11:10:09]   Daniel's CMD plugin v2.8
[11:10:09]     (c) 2014 Daniel_Cortez
[11:10:09]  www.pro-pawn.ru
[11:10:09]   Loaded.
[11:10:09]  Loading plugin: streamer.so
```

Помогите пожалуйста, у меня Ubuntu 14.04.5 32-bit libstdc++5 и 6 установлены

Comment: У вас ведь такие же глаза как и у остальных, почему вы игнорируете то, что написано в логе и не пытаетесь это исправить? (Ключевое слово "Failed")

Comment: программе явно нужна более новая версия libstc++, нежели та, что имеется в вашей версии дистрибутива.

Comment: То есть типа прописать apt-get upgrade libstdc++6?

Comment: Спасибо большое =)